Trying to use GDAL translate to compress hundreds of TIFF files
I am trying to use the code below in a batch file to process over 700 GeoTIFF images. It worked fine when I used a much simpler version of it to do a batch process for conversion of JP2 files to TIFF files as well as changing the EPSG, but after adding additional commands (to further shrink the TIFF file sizes), the process in the command prompt just scrolls through the process and says there are "too many command options." Immediately after that statement, it shows the TIFF file name:
("ERROR 6: Too many command options" with file name immediately thereafter)

Original code:
for %%f in (*.jp2) do (

   echo %%~nf

   gdal_translate -of GTiff %%f %%~nf.tif

)

My modified code example:
for %%f in (*.tif) do (

   echo %%~nf

   gdal_translate -of -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co TILED=YES -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR %%f %%~nf.tif

)

Note that this batch file is in the same directory as the TIFF files, and I am using the Windows command prompt to launch it.
I can use this by just entering the commands and filenames (original & new), but that takes far too long.

Remove -of as you are missing the output format name and the default is GTIFF. If that doesn't work, to debug change your modified gdal_translate -b 1 etc... command to echo gdal_translate -b 1 etc... to print out the commands and look to see if anything obvious is wrong.

In order to avoid the "ERROR 6: Too many command options" error, you need to either remove the -of option or use it correctly like -of GTiff.
See https://gdal.org/en/stable/programs/gdal_translate.html.
Moreover, you cannot overwrite the source dataset, thus you need to specify a destination dataset filename that is different from the source dataset filename.

I tried both ways, no joy. When I insert -of GTiff immediately prior to the bands (1,2,3), it throws an error now saying that the source and destination datasets must be different. I'm suspecting that the "%%~nf.tif" is causing this.

Thanks Andrea! Your answer helped me to find the answer! I added the -of GTiff option, but also modified the last code statement to "%%~nf_1.tif". That corrected the problem! No other errors are popping up, and I've confirmed the settings in the test files with QGIS. Thanks very much again!
